# angular function is not recognized

Tags: angularjs, onscroll

I need to load 20 items of a table with 600 items every time user is near of bottom.  I'm using onscroll in this way but it doesn't recognize the angular function, in this case loadMore():

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<div id="tabla" onscroll="loadMore()">
<table>

  <tr ng-repeat="x in city | limitTo: limit:begin">
    <td> {{ $index +1 }} </td>
    <td> {{ x.city }} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.limit = 20;
        $http.get('city.json').then(function (response) {
         $scope.city = response.data; 
});

$scope.loadMore= function(){

         $scope.limit = $scope.limit+20;
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I get this error:

ReferenceError: loadMore is not defined

Comment: onscroll is searching for JavaScript function, not in angular scope.. You need to write a directive inside that register scroll event on that element with callback passed to directive like `my-scroll="loadMore()"`

Comment: you should make use of a directive such as ng-infinite-scroll